# Consider a cube $C$ centered at origin in $R^3$ what is the number of linear transformations of $R^3$ which maps $C$ onto itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My linear algebra teacher asked me this question:
Consider a cube $C$ centered at origin in $R^3$ what is the number of linear transformations of $R^3$ which maps $C$ onto itself?
I know that linear transformation map eigen vector to itself, but how can I use this property for solving this question?

Comment: Consider the three lines joining centres of opposite faces.

Comment: How many ways are there to pick different eigen values without distorting cube under the linear transformation?

Comment: Linear map that sends cube onto itself permutes its vertices.

Answer (score 0):

One way to proceed can be this:

Find the coordinate of each of the vertices, form a matrix with columns as the coordinates of the vertices. Number of columns will be the number of vertices of the cube. So the entire orientation of the cube in R^3 will be represented as a matrix. As we interchange columns, the orientation changes. Those changes can be tracked down by post-multiplying by elementary matrices. The total number of permutations of the columns will be the total number of elementary matrices that post-multiplies the initial matrix.